# Getting error and crash in Android Emulator when run without internet connection and trying to use camera

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

In my app (run in the emulator), I am not using any internet connection for anything (and don't even have the permission), but get an error (that searches on google claim are due to not releasing an internet resource):

```
A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.     java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
```

My code is simply:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) mCamera = Camera.open(0);
    else mCamera = Camera.open();
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_camera, container, false);

    //Hide progress first
    mProgressContainer = (View)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_camera_progressContainer);
    mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Button takePicture = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_camera_takePictureButton);
    takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if ( mCamera != null) mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, null,mPictureCallback );
        }
    });

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_camera_surfaceView);
    final SurfaceHolder holder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

    //Required only for pre-s.0 devices
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            try
            {
                //Tell camera this is where to draw preview
                if ( mCamera != null) mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error setting up preview display", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int w, int h) {
            if (mCamera == null ) return;

            //Surface changed size, need to tell camera
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size s = getBestSupportedSize( parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), w, h );
            parameters.setPreviewSize(s.width, s.height);

            //Saving picture size
            s = getBestSupportedSize(parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes(), w, h);
            parameters.setPictureSize(s.width, s.height);

            //Tell camera the params
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

            try
            {
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not start preview", e);
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            if (mCamera != null) mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

It crashes just as the fragment is drawn. Why is this happening? How do I fix it? (Connecting my computer to the internet fixes the error, but I need to be able to progam/run the emuator without an internet connection).

Comment: If you are using the Android Emulator the you have to set the Back Crammer a Emulated in the Emulator setting.

Comment: @sarbjot what do you mean by "set the back crammer a emulated"?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the Screen shorts [image]

1.Open the Android Virtual Device manager

2.Edit your Android emulator 
[image]

3.Set Back Camera = (Emulated) as show in screen short.
4.the cammera is look like this.
[image]
I hope it will help you out from this problem

Comment: Does setting it to emulated instead of using the webcam fix this issue? This ony occurs when there's no internet.

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Also, please release the camera along with stoppreview. Your error is mainly because you havent released the resource.